# Amicable numbers function gives the wrong results

Tags: java

As the title described I want to create a function that tells me with both numbers that I give are amicable, but for some reason I get wrong answers, I hope someone will see the problem.

```
public class Amicable{

public static void main(String[] args){

    int n, m;
    int ndivisorsSum = 0;
    int mdivisorsSum = 0;

    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    m = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (n % i == 0){
            ndivisorsSum = ndivisorsSum + i;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < m; i++){
        if (m % i == 0){
            mdivisorsSum = mdivisorsSum + i;
        }
    }

    if (ndivisorsSum == mdivisorsSum) {
        System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " are amicable numbers");
    }else{
        System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " are not amicable numbers");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting wikipedia:

> Amicable numbers are two different numbers so related that the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number. (A proper divisor of a number is a positive factor of that number other than the number itself. For example, the proper divisors of 6 are 1, 2, and 3.) A pair of amicable numbers constitutes an aliquot sequence of period 2. A related concept is that of a perfect number, which is a number that equals the sum of its own proper divisors, in other words a number which forms an aliquot sequence of period 1. Numbers that are members of an aliquot sequence with period greater than 2 are known as sociable numbers.

So what makes you fail in the end is your condition to check whether both numbers are amicable. you need to check if the sum of all divisiors of `n` is equals to `m` and vica verse.

```
int n, m;
int ndivisorsSum = 0;
int mdivisorsSum = 0;

n = 220;
m = 284;

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    if (n % i == 0){
        ndivisorsSum += i;
    }
}

for(int i = 1; i < m; i++){
    if (m % i == 0){
        mdivisorsSum += i;
    }
}

if (ndivisorsSum == m && mdivisorsSum == n) { // Your mistake is here.
    System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " are amicable numbers");
}else{
    System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " are not amicable numbers");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the definition of amicable numbers (according to wikipedia).

It should be

```
if (nDivisorsSum == m && mDivisorsSum == n)
```

You should also check that the numbers are different and positive when they are entered. You could use a `do-while` loop to repeat until a valid input is given.